# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'label_map'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to make an object detection model with the Tensorflow Lite model maker. Here is my code as well as the error I am getting.

```
import numpy as np
import os

from tflite_model_maker.config import ExportFormat
from tflite_model_maker import model_spec
from tflite_model_maker import object_detector

import tensorflow as tf
assert tf.__version__.startswith('2')

tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')
from absl import logging
logging.set_verbosity(logging.ERROR)

spec = model_spec.get('efficientdet_lite0')

train_data, validation_data, test_data =         
object_detector.DataLoader.from_csv('/content/test_labels.csv')

model = object_detector.create(train_data, model_spec=spec, epochs=50, batch_size=8,     
train_whole_model=True, validation_data=validation_data)
```

Here is my full error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-cd74bf318e21> in <module>()
  1 
----> 2 model = object_detector.create(train_data, model_spec=spec, epochs=50, batch_size=8, 
train_whole_model=True, validation_data=validation_data)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist- 
   packages/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/core/task/object_detector.py in create(cls, 
   train_data, model_spec, validation_data, epochs, batch_size, train_whole_model, do_train)
    281           model_spec.compat_tf_versions, compat.get_tf_behavior()))
    282 
    --> 283     object_detector = cls(model_spec, train_data.label_map, train_data)
    284 
    285     if do_train:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'label_map'
```

I am fairly confident my csv is good so I dont know why this is not working.

Comment: After the line `train_data, validation_data, test_data =         
object_detector.DataLoader.from_csv('/content/test_labels.csv')`, you could look at `train_data` with debugger or by printing it. Apparently it is `None` at this stage.

Comment: I will look into this. I am mainly confused because this is code straight from the official tutorial so I am unsure why it would be throwing me errors.

Would I just do print(train_data) to test it out?

Comment: That would be sufficient. If the code is from an official tutorial then by far the most likely reason for your trouble is that the csv file is not found at the given path.

Comment: I tried doing print(train_data) on my csv and got "None" but I also tried on official sample csv files and got the same result.

Comment: It is likely to be in the wrong path. To test, use `f = open('/content/test_labels.csv')` If `FileNotFoundError` is raised, you need to correct your path.

Comment: I will try that. Thank you.

Comment: I added this to my code to try and troubleshoot my problem

`print(train_data)
f = open('/content/test_labels.csv')
print(f)`

and I get the output

`None
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/content/test_labels.csv' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
`

With this, I am still getting the same error both on my csv and an official test csv so I have no idea how to fix this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was that I was at first using only the 'UNASSIGNED' set for all images. While the [AutoML documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/csv-format) says that this should be allowed, in the case of tflite_model_maker this does not appear to be true. So I simply assigned the images into 'TRAIN', 'VALIDATION' and 'TEST' sets and was successfully able to train the model.